# Name of Chinese health system - And any current practitioners in England

Tags: prevention

I read about a chinese health system some time ago (see below)

> [External Link](http://www.seqclinic.com/chinese_medicine.html)
>   Historically, a Chinese Medicine
>   doctor was paid a retainer to keep their patients healthy. If a
>   patient became sick, the doctor would not be paid until the patient’s
>   health returned.

Does anyone know what the european name for this system would be, and how I can find any practitioners in England if there are any.

Comment: I'll be very surprised if any doctor, Chinese or otherwise, is willing to agree to those terms.

Comment: Sounds like insurance